# C# ComplexCollection Dynamic columns

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity framework and have a stored procedure which returns data. Amount of returned columns and columns names are allways different. I have to write that tada into excel, so i have to know, how to select first, second, third and etc. column. My returned data looks like this:

```
Name    JAN11   FEB11
name1   12      45
name2   45      45

Name    JUN12   JUL12   AUG12
name2   5       5       6
name3   12      45      4
```

Any amount of columns is possible.
How would it be possible to know which column name is first, second, etc.
When i am writing to excel, i have to select values of column JAN11, but it is not allways there.

Comment: Please provide more info, f.g., code you currently have.

Comment: I don't have any code which coulc be helpful yet. Maybe there is a way to get column value while providint column name as a string? Instead of `mylist[i].JAN11` i would like to do something like `mylist[i]["JAN11"]`